# getting an error on InitializeComponent() on xaml.cs files

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I will sometimes get a red error that says:

> InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context

Along with the other variables that I have in my `.xaml` that are bound by `x:Name`. The `x:Class` in the Xaml file does correspond to the namespace and class name in my `xaml.cs` file.

The build action for my xaml file is set to "Embedded Resource" and the build action for my `xaml.cs` file is set to "Compile". The error only appears randomly and the project runs like normal even with the red errors. I am developing on windows 8.1 with Visual Studio with Xamarin.

Even though the code runs, I would like to not see those errors appear. Is there any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using shared project you can't make those "errors" disappear. SAP does not recognize the InitializeComponent() method, so it marks it as an error, because of that the code behind does not recognize the x:Name till you run it.

**EDIT 08/11/2015**

PCL shouldn't be giving you this kinds of errors, check that your xaml namespace x:Class and your xaml.cs (code behind) namespace is the same.

Another thing you can do is to update your Xamarin.Forms reference to the latest (pre-release included).

Comment: I am using a portable class library (PCL) type project.

Comment: I did a clean and rebuild and still had those errors. I then copy and pasted the namespace and class name from my xaml.cs file to my xaml file, even though they were both already the same. Errors are now gone and x:Name variables are usable.

Comment: I wanted to see a fix that would have done something more but this works for now thanks.

Comment: Saving files, resaving namespaces, and updating packages aren't fixing this issue for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This helped me:

> In package manager console, issue the following command:
>
> update-package -project your_pcl_project_name -reinstall

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6d4e336-b3b6-45ef-b681-87c351f902e9/xamarin-forms-project-xaml-compilation-error-in-vs15-community-with-update-2-installed?forum=visualstudiogeneral#answers

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Anyone know why this was needed?

Comment: Have no idea. I also had to do this on VS2017